# How do you monitor the progress of dd?

Tags: dd, monitoring

[`dd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dd.1.html) is a wonder. It lets you duplicate a hard drive to another, completely zero a hard drive, etc. But once you launch a `dd` command, there's nothing to tell you of its progress. It just sits there at the cursor until the command finally finishes. So how does one monitor dd's progress?

Answer (score 599, accepted):

From [HowTo: Monitor the progress of dd](https://web.archive.org/web/20150312214618/https://www.serenux.com/2011/02/howto-monitor-the-progress-of-dd/)

You can monitor the progress of `dd` once it's running without halting it by using the `kill` command to send a signal to the process.

After you start `dd`, open another terminal and enter *either*:

```
sudo kill -USR1 $(pgrep ^dd$)
```

*Or*, if you're on BSD or OS X:

```
sudo kill -INFO $(pgrep ^dd$)
```

This will display the progress in the `dd` terminal window without halting the process (by printing to its stderr stream). For example:

```
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=rando bs=1024 count=1048576
335822+0 records in
335821+0 records out
343880704 bytes (344 MB, 328 MiB) copied, 6.85661 s, 50.2 MB/s
```

If you would like to get regular updates of the `dd` progress, then  enter:

```
watch -n5 'sudo kill -USR1 $(pgrep ^dd$)'
```

`watch` will probe the `dd` process every -n seconds (`-n5` = 5 seconds) and report without halting it.

Note the proper single quotes in the commands above.

Comment: This worked, but a couple of comments. First of all, I'm not sure why you escaped your backticks (if it's for the SO editor, you did it incorrectly). Secondly I'd recommend using ^dd$, just in case something else is running with the prefix dd. Finally, you don't need sudo to send the USR1 signal. Otherwise, good answer, +1.

Comment: @gsingh2011 For a description of why sudo is used and each command is placed as it is, read the article it's from (linked at the top of the answer)

Comment: I've added an answer below where I wrap `dd` and `pkill` into a function that can be called more easily than trying to juggle separate commands.

Comment: What about just `killall -USR1 dd`?

Comment: NB! This way interupts dd work under OSX.

Comment: @James, Hmm, but "making it output by prompting it with usr1" is not an intended use right? So would you say that this is actually just a hacky way of doing it?

Comment: @gsingh2011, Well there's no harm typing it again if `sudo kill -USR1 \`pgrep dd\`` doesn't work.

Comment: @Speakus You have to use `kill -INFO $(pgrep ^dd$)` on BSD systems (like OSX).

Comment: `sudo pkill -usr1 dd` is easier to remember, works perfectly fine (at least on Ubuntu 14.04), and is less to type.

Comment: Usually this worked for me, but as I tried it now, `dd` remained in process state D (uninterruptable sleep) and did not answer the kill until it finished. BS was way below file size, however.

Comment: I think the output is not done by watch, but by dd itself. That means that if the dd line is executed in one terminal and the watch line in another, the result will not be what is expected. watch here is really just a loop with a clear screen, that by coincidence clears in sync with dd's output.

Comment: I do `while true; do clean && pkill -usr1 dd && sleep 1; done` because is much easier to read static text :V than using watch in that concrete case. Like that more than the `pv`.

Comment: I like this because I'm afraid `pv` will slow down the transfer, as TeddHansen showed it does. Also, I'll bet lots of people are Googling this because they _already_ started the `dd` operation ;)

Comment: @sudo Like me, for example

Comment: @James the linked site is (at least temporarily) down. To avoid link rot, please consider updating the answer to explain why sudo is necessary, or comment here?

Comment: @Phizes Bare `pkill` is probably unsafe, especially with root. As somebody commented, `sudo` is not needed here. Its safest to use `kill -USR1 $pid` but a bit safer to use `pkill -USR1 -nx dd`.

Comment: This works on my system and it's a bit less to type:  `watch -n 10 kill -USR1  $(pidof dd)`

Comment: @akhan Actually it wouldn't work on my system without root, which makes sense. Should you really be able to prod processes you don't own? Of course if dd is running as a user process, then the signal should be sent by the same user. Could you explain how it's unsafe?

Comment: @Phizes Are you trying to kill a root process or process under another uid?  Also, pkill can match any process that starts with dd, hence the `-nx` flag (`pgrep -l ssh` lists ssh-agent along with ssh). Signals can be sent to different uids and how the process handles them is platform specific. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258503/what-happens-when-a-non-root-user-sends-signals-to-root-users-process) for relevant discussion for linux.

Comment: No need to send INFO on OSX: Just press Ctrl-T.

Comment: `pgrep` alone should not be recommended here, due to the way it matches substrings rather than the actual process name, and could unexpectedly send signals to  other processes too.  It would be better to use `pgrep -x`, or `pidof`, or just pass 'dd' directly to `pkill -x` or `killall`

Comment: @sudo note that sending `SIGUSR1` also affects the performance of `dd`, as writing status info seems to happen in sync with (in the same thread as) the actual transfer; therefore any status writes triggered by the signal temporarily interrupt it.

Comment: No need to use `sudo` with `dd`, you can `chgrp floppy /dev/«device-that-you-will-write-to»`. Then if you are in group `floppy`, you can write to the device with less possibility of destroying stuff (double check the `chgrp`, before continuing).

Comment: Answer by @Torben works like a charm in Mac Catalina as of March 2020.

```sudo kill -INFO $(pgrep ^dd$)```

Comment: THIS NEEDS A WARNING! 2 days lost due to this command, then re-read the rest of the post to see there is an OSX option! Yes I should have read the whole answer, however, you should defo not provide a command that kills the process without a warning!

Comment: On FreeBSD (probably OSX too?) you can actually just press Ctrl+T to send SIGINFO

https://blog.danielisz.org/2018/06/21/the-power-of-ctrlt/

Answer (score 958):

***Update 2016**: If you use GNU coreutils >= 8.24 (default in Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 upwards), you can simply add `status=progress` to your dd command. See method 2 below for details.*

---

## Method 1: By using `pv`

Install `pv` and put it between input / output only `dd` commands.

*Note*: you cannot use it when you already started `dd`.

**From [the package description](https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml):**

> `pv` - Pipe Viewer - is a terminal-based tool for monitoring the
> progress of data through a pipeline. It can be inserted into any
> normal pipeline between two processes to give a visual indication of
> how quickly data is passing through, how long it has taken, how near
> to completion it is, and an estimate of how long it will be until
> completion.

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install pv
```

**Example**

```
dd if=/dev/urandom | pv | dd of=/dev/null
```

**Output**

```
1,74MB 0:00:09 [ 198kB/s] [      <=>                               ]
```

You could specify the approximate size with the `--size` if you want a time estimation.

---

**Example Assuming a 2GB disk being copied from /dev/sdb**

Command without `pv` would be:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=DriveCopy1.dd bs=4096
```

Command with `pv`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb | pv -s 2G | dd of=DriveCopy1.dd bs=4096
```

Output:

```
440MB 0:00:38 [11.6MB/s] [======>                             ] 21% ETA 0:02:19
```

---

**Other uses**

You can of course use `pv` directly to pipe the output to stdout:

```
pv /home/user/bigfile.iso | md5sum
```

**Output**

```
50,2MB 0:00:06 [8,66MB/s] [=======>         ] 49% ETA 0:00:06
```

Note that in this case, `pv` recognizes the size automatically.

---

## Method 2: New `status` option added to `dd` (GNU Coreutils 8.24+)

`dd` in GNU Coreutils 8.24+ (Ubuntu 16.04 and newer) got a new `status` option to display the progress:

#### Example

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null status=progress
```

#### Output

```
462858752 bytes (463 MB, 441 MiB) copied, 38 s, 12,2 MB/s
```

Comment: pv bigfile.iso | dd of=/dev/yourdevice

Comment: Note that the parameters for "dd" are appropriate in the first half (the input part of the pipe): `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=35000 | pv | dd of=VirtualDisk.raw`.

Comment: Can we do `pv bigfile.iso | dd of=VirtualDisk.raw bs=1M count=35000` instead?

Comment: `pv bigfile.iso | dd of=VirtualDisk.raw bs=1M count=35000` works, verified. @SopalajodeArrierez, parameters can be given in the second dd.

Comment: using `pv < /dev/sda > /dev/sdb` seems to get better speed ([source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/523037/how-would-i-speed-up-a-full-disk-dd))

Comment: @phoibos, Why bother with `pv` when `kill -USR1` works? (See answer by  James)

Comment: I've done some testing and the `pv`-method is approximately 40% slower than a direct `dd` with a 5-sec `SIGUSR1`.

Comment: You can also specify the --size option to pv so it will give progress info like ETA.  But I decided to go with the USR1 signal method since I want this to go as fast as possible.

Comment: Note that on the ubuntu live cd you get an `unable to locate package pv`.

Comment: Why does `pv` start reporting a much lower data rate compared to `status=progress` switch for the `dd` command? It appears that the `dd` command has a slower decline in its data rate display, in my test `pv` went down to 120 MB/s within in the first 10 GB, but at 43 GB, dd still shows 147 MB/s.

Comment: FYI on speed. Tests on my computer with Samsung 840 PRO SSD: `dd  if=/dev/urandom | pv | of=/dev/sdb` gives ~18MB/s write, `dd if=/dev/zero | pv | of=/dev/sdb` gives ~80MB/s, and plain old `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` gives ~550MB/s (close to SSD max write speed). All with `bs=4096000`.

Comment: You may need to do `sudo apt-add-repository universe; sudo apt-get update` in order to install pv.

Comment: @ phoibos - I am on 16.04 &   GNU Coreutils 8.25 and  "status=progress" did not work for me using sudo  dd if=/dev/sda2 conv=sync,noerror bs=64M progress=status | gzip -c  >$BAKfilename - maybe the missing "of=" sabotages it

Comment: @TeddHansen That's concerning. Makes me not want to use `pv`. Maybe a CPU bottleneck? Was your CPU running full capacity due to `pv`?

Comment: This is a few weeks ago now, so not sure. But I think I checked CPU and that was not the bottleneck. (It would of course be the most obvious thing to check.) The computer was a 4 year old high end desktop (good spec, custom built by me).

Comment: @DavidWalker, I messed this up in another comment, but it has to be 'status=progress', and not 'progress=status'.

Comment: @phoibos: `status=progress` is a huge and convenient time-saver. No need to install pv just to get progress any more. I'm so happy about that! :) It's a shame I can't upvote your answer twice.

Comment: Direct I/O (open mode `O_DIRECT`) should work, but your kernel and/or `dd` may not support it. `status=progress` will select the speed and process of writing to the kernel cache, but the execution of the `sync` to return the records to disk, we do not see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

Comment: The slowness of `dd if=foo | pv | dd of=bar` vs `pv <foo >bar` is probably due to all of the copying of data: the data is read from device `foo` into the first `dd`'s memory space, then copied from there into `pv`'s memory space using a 64K (on Linux at least) pipe buffer, then copied again into the second `dd`'s memory space using another 64K buffer, then finally written to device `bar`

Comment: wonderful answer!

Comment: If I only saw this page before starting this dd command... If they added `status`, why didn't they enable it by default?

Comment: No need to use `sudo` with `dd`, you can `chgrp floppy /dev/«device-that-you-will-write-to»`. Then if you are in group floppy, you can write to the device with less possibility of destroying stuff (double check the `chgrp`, before continuing).

Comment: @DamnVegetables because suddenly changing the default output of a program could break important scripts that base their actions on the expected output. The option's there if you want it, but in the meantime the added feature won't break existing code. You could always add an alias in your `.bashrc` along the lines of `alias dds='dd status=progress'`, then just use `dds` instead of `dd`. You could "overwrite" dd with an alias e.g. `alias dd='dd status=progress'` but that could be more dangerous (especially if *you* have any scripts that run dd and expect certain output!)

Comment: Could it be that `pv file| dd of=device` is slower because somehow it reads from the disk while writing? I wondered why writing is so slow using PV and saw that it READS a lot. Why? This is a 250 GB disk which sure has no 4k sectors!

Comment: method 2 seems to be the answer

Comment: There is yet another option (I had a faulty USB and method 1 & 2 from this post failed) > 3rd method did work > `watch -n5 'cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i dirty'` helped me get updated every 5 seconds about the amount of data that was left to be written to disk. SImple & perfect

Comment: `status=progress` seems to slow down significantly the copy operation; noticeable on slower devices like raspberry pi's

Answer (score 123):

A few handy sample usages with `pv` and less typing or more progress then other answers:

First you will need to install `pv`, with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install pv
```

Then some examples are:

```
pv -n /dev/urandom | dd of=/dev/null
pv -tpreb source.iso | dd of=/dev/BLABLA bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror
```

<sup>Note: the first sample is 5 characters less typing then `dd if=/dev/urandom | pv | dd of=/dev/null`.</sup>

And my favorite for cloning a disk drive (replace X with drive letters):

```
(pv -n /dev/sdX | dd of=/dev/sdX bs=128M conv=notrunc,noerror) 2>&1 | dialog --gauge "Running dd command (cloning), please wait..." 10 70 0
```

[image: screenshot]

source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-dd-command-show-progress-while-coping/

<sub>Also for archiving myself.</sub>

Comment: you will need to install also `dialog` with the command `apt-get install dialog`

Comment: *LOVE* the `dialog` example. _SERENITY NOW_!

Comment: Can you only call that dialog with python?

Comment: Calling from python? You may use it with "subprocess.Popoen". Despite not recommended because of security issues. Without graphicish results, this guy has made a similar impact: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578907-python-awesome-dd/   Check out I guess.

Comment: `brew install pv dialog` for Mac. Also this gentleman computes with style. Bravo.

Comment: Feng Shui style: `pv < source >destination`

Comment: On my system, when `pv` is reading a file, it will read the entire file in one chunk, making the transfer jump to 100% and then you wait for `dd` to finish writing the data. What fixed that for me was adding `oflag=dsync` to `dd`. So: `(pv -tpreb file | dd of=/dev/sdX bs=1MB oflag=dsync conv=notrunc,noerror) 2>&1` for console progress reporting and for the dialog progress bar `(pv -n file | dd of=/dev/sdX bs=1MB oflag=dsync conv=notrunc,noerror) 2>&1 | dialog --gauge "Message..." 10 70 0`. @zevero mentions the oflag in his answer.

Answer (score 85):

For the sake of completeness:

Version **8.24** of the *GNU coreutils* includes a patch for dd introducing a parameter to print the progress.

[The commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commit;h=af2a4ed22594badd2719c0123441d69b17bd8328) introducing this change has the comment:

> dd: new **status=progress** level to print stats periodically

Many distributions, including *Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS* use this version.

Comment: just wanna add how I've compiled 8.24 coreutils: `apt install build-essential` and `apt-get build-dep coreutils`, then download coreutils-8.25.tar.xz, `tar xvf coreutils-8.25.tar.xz` `configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/local` and run `make`. Newly compiled `dd` will be under `src` dir. You can copy it to /bin and replace existing one or jus run as src/dd

Comment: Cool! I like this feature. And it took just about 30 years to teach dd to print progress output. :-)

Comment: What a relief! I will immediately add this argument in a dd shell alias.

Comment: Note that the status will sometimes print with two numbers, one in SI units and the equivalent value in binary units (e.g.10 MB, 9.5 MiB).

Comment: ... how periodically does it print stats? Because mine seems to print stats once, and then doesn't update until it's done.

Answer (score 72):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> while `dd` is running, and it will output the progress (in bytes):

```
load: 1.51  cmd: dd 31215 uninterruptible 0.28u 3.67s
321121+0 records in
321120+0 records out
164413440 bytes transferred in 112.708791 secs (1458745 bytes/sec)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Kubuntu Trusty. Possibly conflicting key bindings?

Comment: Great way. It works under OSX, but does not work under ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The first line is generated by the OS X, only the latter 3 lines are from `dd`.

Comment: You should be able to use kill -INFO on a BSD like OS X

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu.  Ctrl-T/Ctrl-Shift-T only output `^T` to the terminal (except many terminal apps will intercept Ctrl-Shift-T and open a new tab).  Many searchers on OSX/BSD may appreciate this answer, but it should be made clear that it's not for Ubuntu (or GNU/LInux in general?)

Comment: On Mac it appears just Ctrl+T works, but Ctrl+Shift+T does not.

Answer (score 37):

The best is using http://dcfldd.sourceforge.net/ it is easy to install through apt-get

Comment: thanks for the pointer to dcfldd, very compatible with dd but some good new features. I especially like the standard progress.

Comment: Why dcfldd isn't more well known is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: probably for its name.

Comment: It has the options of `dd` and option `status=on` by default, for progress messages, `statusinterval=N` (N in blocks) for message update frequency and `sizeprobe=[if|of]` for a percentage indicator. I will alias it to `DD` :)

Answer (score 30):

Native progress status was added to dd!!!

The new version of Coreutils (8.24) adds a progress status to the `dd` tool:

Usage on Xubuntu 15.10:

Open a terminal and type these commands:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.24.tar.xz
tar -xf coreutils-8.24.tar.xz
cd coreutils-8.24
./configure && make -j $(nproc)
```

Run `dd` as root:

```
sudo su
cd src
./dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sda conv=noerror status=progress
```

You will see: Bytes, seconds and speed (Bytes/second).

To check the versions of `dd`:

Native:

```
dd --version
```

New:

```
cd coreutils-8.24/src
./dd --version
```

Answer (score 22):

If you have already started dd, and if you are writing a file such as when creating a copy of a pendrive to disk, you can use the watch command to constantly observe the size of the output file to see changes and estimate completion.

```
watch ls -l /pathtofile/filename
```

To see only file size (h-human view):

```
watch ls -sh /pathtofile/filename
```

Comment: Also a viable method...

Comment: Useful, though this doesn't necessarily work if you're piping the dd output to something other than a file (eg gzip'ing before writing it to disk).

Comment: Does not work on special files.

Answer (score 15):

The `dd | pv | dd` triad made my 50GB vm copy take 800 seconds, as opposed to 260 seconds using just dd. With this pipeline, at least, pv has no idea how big the input file is so it won't be able to tell you how far along you are so there's no disadvantage to doing it as follows- and you get a nice speed advantage:

I would avoid pv on anything large, and (if using Bash):

Control-Z the dd process

`bg` to put it in background. Observe that `bg` will give you output like `[1] 6011` where the latter number is a process id. So, do:

`while true; do kill -USR1 process_id ; sleep 5; done`

where process_id is the process id you observed. Hit Control-C when you see something like:

```
[1]+  Done dd if=/path/file.qcow2 of=/dev/kvm/pxetest bs=4194304 conv=sparse
-bash: kill: (60111) - No such process
```

You are done.

Edit: Silly Systems Administrator! Automate your life, don't work! If I have a long dd process that I want to monitor, here's a one-liner that will take care of the whole enchilada for you; put this all on one line:

```
 dd if=/path/to/bigimage of=/path/to/newimage conv=sparse bs=262144 & bgid=$!; while true; do sleep 1; kill -USR1 $bgid || break; sleep 4; done
```

You can, of course, script it, perhaps make $1 your input file and $2 your output file. This is left as an exercise for the reader. Note that you need that little sleep before the kill or the kill may die trying to send a signal to dd when it's not ready yet. Adjust your sleeps as desired (maybe even remove the second sleep altogether).

Bash- FTW!  :-)

Comment: Compress the `while` loop. Use `watch`.

Comment: @muru it depends. I don't know about your system but on CentOS7* the output is a little garbled; it's readable but does not look orderly. Also it stomps over your previous output so you lose history of the speed of your dd; mine varies between 20 MB/s and 300 MB/s. It's interesting to watch the numbers vary and instructive too. I think some of the large variance is due to LVM thin pools increasing the allocation for an LV I'm writing to.    * yes this is an ubuntu forum but I got here looking for "dd monitor progress". It's the first result on Google.

Comment: Oh, I meant in another terminal or screen window, run `sudo watch pkill dd`. Then watch `dd` output the stats comfortably.

Comment: Won't pkill send SIGTERM by default? I don't even want to experiment, as pgrep dd comes up with 3 pid's when running a single dd: kthreadd, oddjob, and the dd. I'm afraid of what pkill will do. You could send the -USR1 signal with pkill but again I don't know if that's safe to send to the kernel thread or to obbjob. The watch command looks cleaner but it seems like a lot of extra steps just to avoid a while loop. Generally if I'm doing a dd in one window I'm going to do something right afterwards in the same shell. The while loop is safe: you know EXACTLY which pid gets the signal.

Comment: mostly I don't care which pids get the signal, since I use `watch pkill -USR1 -x dd`. Since I also use `watch` for other similar tasks, this one comes naturally.

Comment: ...I note that Robru's answer which uses a pkill should be safe, as it restricts the pkill to only the dd binary, using the `^dd$` syntax. Update: Ah, -x. Ok that's better.

Answer (score 14):

http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/06/show-progress-during-dd-copy.html

Basically:

```
kill -USR1 < dd pid >
```

Comment: "pkill -USR1 dd" is the simplest version I'm aware of (as long as you're just running one instance of dd, anyway).  On my system I need sudo: "sudo pkill -USR1 dd".  Works after you've typed the dd command, and you don't need to install anything new.

Answer (score 11):

### On Ubuntu 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with dd (coreutils) Version **8.25** . Hence the option `status=progress` **is** Supported :-)

To use it, just add `status=progress` along with your `dd` command.

Example :

```
dd bs=4M if=/media/severus/tools-soft/OperatingSystems/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/null status=progress && sync
```

Gives the status as

```
1282846183 bytes (1.2 GiB, 1.1 GiB) copied, 14.03 s, 101.9 MB/s
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### Easiest is:

```
 dd if=... of=... bs=4M status=progress oflag=dsync
```

`oflag=dsync` will keep your writing in sync, so information of `status=progress` is more accurate. However it might be a bit slower.

Comment: according to https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html , using `conv=fsync` is better

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm doing dd to a remote lvm2 and the bs=4M increased my transfer by a factor of 20 and the progress indication is wonderful.

Answer (score 9):

Use option `status=progress` to get the progress during the transfert.

In addition, `conv=fsync` will display I/O errors.

Example:

```
sudo dd if=mydistrib.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress conv=fsync
```

Answer (score 7):

This one forces dd to provide stats every 2 seconds which is default for watch:

```
watch killall -USR1 dd
```

To change from every 2 seconds to every 5 seconds, add -n 5 option like this:

```
watch -n 5 killall -USR1 dd
```

Answer (score 5):

I really like ddrescue, it works as dd but gives output and doesn't fail on errors, on the contrary it has a very advanced algorithm an tries really hard to do a successful copy... There are also many GUIs for it

Project: [https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/)

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ddrescue

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have created bash wrapper over `dd` that will use `pv` to show progress. Put it into your `.bashrc` and use `dd` as usual:

```
# dd if=/dev/vvg0/root of=/dev/vvg1/root bs=4M
    2GB 0:00:17 [ 120MB/s] [===========================================================>] 100%            
0+16384 records in
0+16384 records out
2147483648 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 18.3353 s, 117 MB/s
```

Source:

```
dd()
{
    local dd=$(which dd); [ "$dd" ] || {
        echo "'dd' is not installed!" >&2
        return 1
    }

    local pv=$(which pv); [ "$pv" ] || {
        echo "'pv' is not installed!" >&2
        "$dd" "$@"
        return $?
    }

    local arg arg2 infile
    local -a args
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        arg2=${arg#if=}
        if [ "$arg2" != "$arg" ]
        then
            infile=$arg2
        else
            args[${#args[@]}]=$arg
        fi
    done

    "$pv" -tpreb "$infile" | "$dd" "${args[@]}"
}
```

Comment: Good way but it does not work with commands like sudo or time.

Comment: Put it into /usr/local/bin/dd with this on top: `#!/bin/bash`. On bottom: `tmp=":${PATH}:"; tmp=${tmp/:/usr/local/bin:/:}; tmp=${tmp%:}; PATH=${tmp#:}; dd "$@"` Or you may wish to hardcode `dd` location. Then use `local dd=/usr/bin/dd`. Don't forget to add executable bit: `chmod +x /usr/local/dd`.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anybody from CentOS land happens to find this thread...

**The 'status=progress' option works with CentOS 7.5 and 7.6**

The answer above by @davidDavidson implies the feature was newly added in Coreutils 8.24.

> Version 8.24 of the GNU coreutils includes a patch for dd introducing a parameter to print the progress.

This may be the case, but CentOS might not be following the same versioning scheme.

The version of Coreutils that comes with CentOS 7.6.1810 is:

```
coreutils-8.22-23.el7.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
```

And the version of dd that is installed is:

```
[root@hostname /]# dd --version
dd (coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Paul Rubin, David MacKenzie, and Stuart Kemp.
```

This shows versions **8.22**.

However, I have tested the 'status=progress' with dd on both CentOS 7.5 and CentOS 7.6 (both with version 8.22 of Coreutils) and it functions properly.

I don't know why RedHat chooses to use such an old version of Coreutils but the functionality does exist with 8.22.

Answer (score 2):

So today I got a little frustrated with trying to run `kill` in a loop while `dd` was running, and came up with this method for running them in parallel, easily:

```
function vdd {
    sudo dd "$@" &
    sudo sh -c "while pkill -10 ^dd$; do sleep 5; done"
}
```

Now just use `vdd` anywhere you'd normally use `dd` (it passes all arguments directly through) and you'll get a progress report printed every 5s.

The only downside is that the command doesn't return immediately when dd completes; so it's possible that this command can keep you waiting an extra 5s after dd returns before it notices and exits.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch the progress of any coreutils program using `progress - Coreutils Progress Viewer`.

It can monitor:

cp mv **dd** tar cat rsync grep fgrep egrep cut sort md5sum sha1sum sha224sum sha256sum sha384sum sha512sum adb gzip gunzip bzip2 bunzip2 xz unxz lzma unlzma 7z 7za zcat bzcat lzcat split gpg

You can see the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/progress.1.html)

You can use it in a seperate terminal window while the command is running or launch it with the dd command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=file.img & progress -mp $!
```

Here `&` forks the first command and continues immediately instead of waiting until the command ends.

The progress command is launched with: `-m` so it waits until the monitored process ended, `-p` so it monitors a given pid and `$!` is the last command pid.

If you issue dd with sudo, you have to too with progress too:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=file.img &
sudo progress -m
# with no -p, this will wait for all coreutil commands to finish
# but $! will give the sudo command's pid
```

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu 20.04 system I use, dcfldd

```
❯ sudo dcfldd if=20210708.img status=on of=/dev/sdd bs=1M sizeprobe=if

[46% of 3814Mb] 1792 blocks (1792Mb) written. 00:00:28 remaining.
```

Here in sizeprobe we have 3 options, if,of,BYTES which is to determine the size of the input,output or an amount of BYTES for use with status messages

status is by default 'on', I just used explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

To add on @JSBack great answer, here is how you can get a dialog to wipe a disk with dd:

```
(dd if=/dev/zero | pv -s $(lsblk -b -o SIZE /dev/sdX | tail -n 1) -n | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX bs=1M) 2>&1  | dialog --gauge "Wiping disk /dev/sdX, Please wait..." 10 70 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago, I got this dd progress script from somewhere (I do not recall where, and in my OPS infancy didn't include source or references in the code comments. Thanks to the original developer, and apologies for not having the source info):

```
#!/bin/bash
# show progress of dd command
# example: sdd.sh if=/dev/random of=random10M.dat bs=1M count=10
# script modified to redirect to stdout and show only units less than MB

unset parameters
ibs=512
obs=512
iconvrate=1024
oconvrate=1024

while [ -n "${1}" ] ; do
    key="${1%%=*}"
    value="${1#*=}"
    case "${key}" in
        (ibs)   ibs="${value}" ;;
        (obs)   obs="${value}" ;;
        (bs)    ibs="${value}" ; obs="${value}" ;;
    esac

    parameters="${parameters} ${1}"
    shift
done

#   BLOCKS  and  BYTES  may  be  followed by the following multiplicative suffixes: xM M, c 1, w 2, b 512, kB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M
#   1024*1024, GB 1000*1000*1000, G 1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.

case "${ibs: -1}" in
    (c) ibs="${ibs%c}" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (w) ibs="$(( ${ibs%w} * 2))" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (b) ibs="${ibs%b}" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (B) ibs="${ibs%B}" ; iconvrate=1000 ;
        case "${ibs: -1}" in
            (K) ibs="$(( ${ibs%K} * 1000 ))" ;;
            (M) ibs="$(( ${ibs%M} * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (G) ibs="$(( ${ibs%G} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (T) ibs="$(( ${ibs%T} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (P) ibs="$(( ${ibs%P} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (E) ibs="$(( ${ibs%E} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (Z) ibs="$(( ${ibs%Z} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (Y) ibs="$(( ${ibs%Y} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
        esac ;;
    (K) ibs="$(( ${ibs%K} * 1024 ))" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (M) ibs="$(( ${ibs%M} * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (G) ibs="$(( ${ibs%G} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (T) ibs="$(( ${ibs%T} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (P) ibs="$(( ${ibs%P} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (E) ibs="$(( ${ibs%E} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (Z) ibs="$(( ${ibs%Z} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
    (Y) ibs="$(( ${ibs%Y} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; iconvrate=1024 ;;
esac

case "${obs: -1}" in
    (c) obs="${obs%c}" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (w) obs="$(( ${obs%w} * 2))" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (b) obs="${obs%b}" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (B) obs="${obs%B}" ; oconvrate=1000 ;
        case "${obs: -1}" in
            (K) obs="$(( ${obs%K} * 1000 ))" ;;
            (M) obs="$(( ${obs%M} * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (G) obs="$(( ${obs%G} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (T) obs="$(( ${obs%T} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (P) obs="$(( ${obs%P} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (E) obs="$(( ${obs%E} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (Z) obs="$(( ${obs%Z} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
            (Y) obs="$(( ${obs%Y} * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ))" ;;
        esac ;;
    (K) obs="$(( ${obs%K} * 1024 ))" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (M) obs="$(( ${obs%M} * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (G) obs="$(( ${obs%G} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (T) obs="$(( ${obs%T} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (P) obs="$(( ${obs%P} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (E) obs="$(( ${obs%E} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (Z) obs="$(( ${obs%Z} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
    (Y) obs="$(( ${obs%Y} * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))" ; oconvrate=1024 ;;
esac

tmp="$( mktemp )"
rm -f "${tmp}"
mkfifo "${tmp}"
chmod 0600 "${tmp}"

dd ${parameters} 2> ${tmp} &
pid=${!}

SECONDS=0
while [ -d /proc/${pid} ] ; do
    sleep 1
    kill -USR1 ${pid} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
#114718+0 records in
#114717+0 records out
#58735104 bytes (59 MB) copied, 5.61526 seconds, 10.5 MB/s

    read line1
    read line2
    read line3
    isuff=""
    osuff=""
    ipssuff=""
    opssuff=""
    line1="${line1%+*}"
    line2="${line2%+*}"
    in="$(( ${line1} * ${ibs} ))"
    out="$(( ${line2} * ${obs} ))"
    ips="$(( ${in} / ${SECONDS} ))"
    ops="$(( ${out} / ${SECONDS} ))"
#   for x in k M G T P E Z F ; do
    for x in k M ; do
        if [ ${ips} -gt ${iconvrate} ] ; then
            ips="$(( ${ips} / ${iconvrate} ))"
            ipssuff="${x}"
            [ ${iconvrate} -eq 1000 ] && ipssuff="${ipssuff}B"
        fi
        if [ ${ops} -gt ${oconvrate} ] ; then
            ops="$(( ${ops} / ${oconvrate} ))"
            opssuff="${x}"
            [ ${oconvrate} -eq 1000 ] && opssuff="${opssuff}B"
        fi
        if [ ${in} -gt ${iconvrate} ] ; then
            in="$(( ${in} / ${iconvrate} ))"
            isuff="${x}"
            [ ${iconvrate} -eq 1000 ] && isuff="${ipssuff}B"
        fi
        if [ ${out} -gt ${oconvrate} ] ; then
            out="$(( ${out} / ${oconvrate} ))"
            osuff="${x}"
        fi
    done
    echo -en "\rIn: ${in}${isuff} (${ips}${ipssuff}/sec) - Out: ${out}${osuff} (${ops}${opssuff}/sec)" > /dev/stderr
done < "${tmp}"
echo > /dev/stderr
rm -f "${tmp}"
```

This script starts dd and sends it a HUP signal each second, parsing the output to make it more readable and showing the progress data in a single updating line.

I didn't write the code and never took the time to optimize it.