# I want to see the progress of dd but when I type this command "sudo dcfldd" Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize that command

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to write Raspbian to an SD card and see the progress of the write procedure, is there another command that will do this?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install dcfldd`.

Comment: You really should clean up your question - it took me some time to gather what that was about. Remember we hope that questions and their answers will be useful for a longer time.

Comment: Regarding progress of dd - consider checking this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd

Answer (score 1):

To see the progress of `dd`, You can use eg. this command to send usr1 signal. When `dd` receive the signal it will print it's current status.

**Open an extra terminal window and copy paste this:**

`sudo kill -usr1 $(ps aux | grep " dd " | grep -v sudo | grep -v grep | awk 'begin{}{print  $2}end')`

If you want to do it manually, use `ps aux` and find the pid of `dd`.If you run `dd` with `sudo`, you should also use `sudo` for `kill` command. `sudo kill -usr1 pid`

Edit:
Found a shorter one-line here using `pgrep` https://askubuntu.com/a/215521/196592

However, when I am at it, I see no reason for not using `pkill` instead eg. `sudo pkill -USR1 ^dd`

Comment: I will give that a try next time I dd it finished writing while I was waiting for replies up votes in the future

Comment: After reading further on dcfldd I wonder why it isn't incorporated into ubu/linux as a standard command