# Anyone managed to get a live ISO out of a running Ubuntu system?

Tags: iso

Anyone managed to get a live ISO out of a running Ubuntu system?
I tried to use Distroshare Ubuntu Imager as shown here:
https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/create-custom-ubuntu-distribution-distroshare-ubuntu-imager/

And the live version worked fine, but when tried to install it the installation always crash.
When I looked at GitHub this is a familiar problem.
If anyone know how to solve it - I will be very grateful!

Comment: @Nmath nah he wants this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152149/move-system-to-new-ssd-with-dd-command though it is not a live session it does make a new system on another disk.

Comment: amir: there are 2 options: both listed in the comments. 1 gets you a live session from a default ISO. The 2nd copies a current system to another harddisk you can boot from. NEITHER will create a live session of the current installed OS and i have never seen a tool doing so. The 1st though is easier if you really want a live session: copy your CACHE DEBs over into the live session and you are  halfway there.

Comment: Well there was a tool called Pinguybuilder that used to work. also systemback.. Anyway thank you, I will continue to look.

Comment: I didn't have good results with Pinguybuilder. Systemback and Clonezilla worked for me. There are others. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/18/vmware-v2p/#Summary